# C++ program to check if a given string is a palindrome

Tags: function, return-value, palindrome

The problem here is that it can't be a string from user input. There are 7 strings, 6 of them are numbers and one is a word "abba". I have so far written much of the code but I'm having trouble finding a way to test the 7 strings that I must use for the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isNumPalindrome(string str);

int main ()
{
    string str;
    str = "10", "32", "222", "abba", "444244", "67867876", "123454321";
    int userExit;

    bool isNum = isNumPalindrome;

    if (isNumPalindrome)
    {
        cout << str << " is a palindrome";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << str << " is not a palindrome";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Press any key to exit: ";
    cin >> userExit;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool isNumPalindrome(string str)
{
    int length = str.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
        if (str[i] != str[length - 1 - i])
            return false;

        return true;
}
```

As you can see, I haven't quite figured out **how to perform a function in main to take the return and output a statement.** I need to find out how to test multiple strings, and then how to use the return statement to print something like `cout << str << "` is not a palindrome.";

Comment: Also I know I have included unneeded headers and I stopped where I declared isNum to be isNumPalindrome, so it is incorrect already.

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/26-boolean-values/

Comment: You need to do some reading on how to call and use functions in C++. This has many problems.

Comment: I understand it's very rough around the edges. If I had been allowed to use user input, I wouldn't have any problems. But I'm beginning, and this threw me off.

Comment: Very rough? This is a mess in so many ways... You need to look at some c++ tutorials. You seem to have no understanding at all of arrays, functions etc.

Comment: The algorithm to test the string is correct, and I have the function prototype right, but I have literally just started learning about return statements. I just need to know how to test multiple strings without user input. I've tried a variety of methods already.

Comment: Well `string str` should be be an array, and then just call `isPalindrome(str[i])` in a loop.

Comment: Well the reason I have to do this without an array is because next week I begin learning to use arrays. Before I study a concept, I get assigned to write a program using unconventional means in order to familiarize myself with the wrong way of doing this. It isn't an efficient process, it's just what my instructor wants.

Comment: I ended up being able to use reference variables and changing the functiontype to int. The return was a variable isNum that I defined as 1 in the nested if statement in my palindrome function. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `str = "one", "two", "three";` gets `str` set to `"three"`... the `,` operator does that. Besides, `str` can contain *one* string, trying to asign more just doesn't work. The name `IsNumPalindrome` you asign to the (non-defined) variable `IsNum` is a pointer to a function, if you then ask `if(IsNum)` it won't ever be the null pointer, so always true.

I could go on. There seems to be hadrly a line without gross errors or grave misunderstandings of C++.

Comment: I know declaring multiple strings doesn't work, this is by no means my finished (or original) code. I started off using the palindrome function with the algorithm, returning both true and false. Then I tried a variable return, but ended up chopping up everything to make it work. This is a frankenstein program. I've searched everything I can to figure this out, but I haven't found one result yet they gives me any help in using my palindrome function to test a set of strings.

Comment: You don't test a set of strings... You just call the function in a loop.

Comment: The first time I tried to loop, it returned true for every string, even though they were not all palindromes. I have tried both if and do repetition but no luck. I understand this code really sucks, this is my first legit program using a value-returning function. The code is unimportant, I just wanted to know a good method of using this palindrome function on 7 strings. I'm having a major brainfart.

Comment: But as stated above, it is because I was using a pointer and the variable returns true always.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str;
str = "10", "32", "222", "abba", "444244", "67867876", "123454321";
```

change to

```
std:vector< std::string > vecOfStrings = { "10", "32", "222", "abba", "444244", "67867876", "123454321" };
```

Then just loop through the vector and pass each string to the function

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vecOfStrings.size(); i++) {
    if ( isNumPalindrome( vecOfStrings[i] ) ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good method using an array. My instructor would like to make this difficult by forcing us to use an inefficient method to implement this function, which is why I haven't been able to use an array yet.

Comment: Can't say I see the point in learning to be inefficient. Not using built in functions/containers/algorithms so you can learn what goes on underneath is useful but here being inefficient is really just declaring a new string for each number, and calling the function for each string. Teaches you nothing new after the first call.

Comment: It's really just so we use better functions in the following chapters (which introduce us to them). I will mostly likely use your array in the end, whether it gets me a good grade or not.

Comment: Well I have given up. Is there a specific header I need to use this array? I'm going to use it.

Comment: You need to #include <vector> to use vectors